# Handle service start after unclean reboot

Tags: systemd

Facing this weird issue after a unclean shutdown/reboot of the host:

```
Found left-over process NNNN (<daemon>) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
This usually indicates unclean termination or a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
```

One of the daemon refuses to come up! But if I do a `restart`, it comes back up!
Is there anyway to handle this in the `systemd` service unit file ?

This happens only on a unclean reboot and not otherwise!

Comment: This is probably due to systemd's control files for the daemon in /run (locks, sockets and `pid` files) which are usually cleaned up on proper shutdown.

Comment: Thanks @Samveen, is there a way to know which files/sockets these are ?

Comment: See the log lines before this error message. That might give you some details about the possible sources.